# Table cells equal widths on resize and overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a table as below:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

It has a width of 100%. I have to display in such a way that all cells have equal widths on re-size and in overflow. I gave it `word-wrap: break-word` so that the text won't overflow from cell.

But what I want is to set it a max width, and all columns should have equal width on re-size. How can I make this possible?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/HD8e7/) is my fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you after the behaviour of [`table-layout: fixed`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#fixed-table-layout)?

```
.table1 {
    border: #FFFF00 2px solid;
    width: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    table-layout: fixed
}
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/GcvPk/

Comment: Hm, I definitely forgot about `table-layout: fixed`, which is actually [well-supported across browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tables.html). +1